# not able to load php_printer.dll in windows7 64 bit OS and wamp, php5.4?

Tags: php

i want to use printer_list functionality in my php project.. please give me proper instructions and a proper php_printer.dll file for my wind7 os and i'm using php 5.4 and wamp server.. ive tried a lot stuffs seeing through forums and good but nothing helpd me.. i'm getting the server priblem after i load thae file

even the simple code given below is not working

```
foreach (printer_list(PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS) as $printer)
    {echo "waste";
        $curprin = strtoupper($printer["NAME"]);
        echo "<option value=\"" . addslashes($curprin) . "\"" . (($curprin == $user["drucker"]) ? " selected" : "") . ">$curprin\n";
    }
```

Comment: what server problem do you get?

Comment: this is wat i'm getting... i'm not able to run any other files unless i comment ;extension=php_printer.dll   ...Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.